# C "for" loop iterating only once

Tags: c, pointers, for-loop

For context, I'm trying to write code that solve [this problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/breaking-best-and-worst-records) in C.

The problem is relatively simple. The first input is an integer that represent the number of scores in a stream of scores. The following inputs are all integers that represent scores. The program should read through the stream of scores and return two values: the number of times the record for best score was broken, and the number of times the record for worst score was broken.

I have this solution written down.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getRecord(int n, int s[], int *max_records, int *min_records)
{
    int max_score, min_score;
    max_score = min_score = s[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] > max_score)
        {
            (*max_records)++;
            max_score = s[i];
        }
        if (s[i] < min_score)
        {
            (*min_records)++;
            min_score = s[i];
        }

        printf("%d %d\n", max_score, min_score);  // inserted to see values
        return 0;
    }
}

int main(char args[])
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int s[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &s[i]);
    int max_records = 0;
    int min_records = 0;

    getRecord(n, s, &max_records, &min_records);
    printf("%d %d\n", max_records, min_records);
}
```

For some reason, the for loop iterates only once when this program is running, no matter what input I use.

Comment: there are only two valid signatures for the `main()` function: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`   The posted code has: `int main( cgar args[] `  which matches none of the valid signatures.  So the compiler complains about the signature.  Then the compiler goes on to complain that the parameter `args` is not used

Comment: the function: `getRecord()` has a `return` statement in the middle of the `for()` loop that is always executed. AND there is no `return value` statement just before the final `}`

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: why have the return type from` getRecords()` be other than `void` as no useful information is returned AND the call in `main()` ignores the returned value?

Comment: when wanting the user to input some value, always prompt the user, then validate the input.  I.E. never trust the user to do the right thing,  especially (as in the posted code) the user is left looking at a blank screen, with a blinking cursor and no indication of what they are expected to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have `return 0` inside your loop.

Change it to:

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    if (s[i] > max_score)
    {
        (*max_records)++;
        max_score = s[i];
    }
    if (s[i] < min_score)
    {
        (*min_records)++;
        min_score = s[i];
    }

    printf("%d %d\n", max_score, min_score);  // inserted to see values
}
return 0;
```

Comment: Thanks. I had a feeling it was something silly like this.